# Convert JSON list of integers to String in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get list of integers from user and convert those to comma separated string before save model in Django Rest Framework.

My model is like this:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    regions = models.TextField(validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[0-9,]+$')])
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and my Serializer:

```
class MessageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    regions_list = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField())

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'regions_list', 'created_at')
        read_only_fields = ('created_at')
```

My input:

```
{
  "name": "TEST",
  "regions_list": [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

How can I convert regions_list to comma separated string (regions) in db?

**Django**: 1.10
**DRF**: 3.5

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I overrode `to_representation` and `to_internal_value` methods. It works good for me.

```
class MessageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    regions_list = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField())

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'regions_list', 'created_at')
        read_only_fields = ('created_at')

    def to_representation(self, instance: Message):
        instance.regions_list = [int(i) for i in instance.regions.split(',')]
        return super(MessageSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        ret = super(MessageSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
        if ret['regions_list']:
            ret['regions'] = ','.join(str(i) for i in ret['regions_list'])

        return ret
```

Answer (score 4):

You can override `create` method in `MessageSerializer`:

```
class MessageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    # .... 

    def create(self, validated_data):
        regions_string = ','.join(validated_data.pop('regions_list', []))
        validated_data['regions'] = regions_string
        return Message.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: tnx @Yevhen. When new instance returns and I want to send response to user `Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)` I get this error: `Original exception text was: 'Message' object has no attribute 'regions_list'.` How about this one?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a PostgresSQL database, you can use the Django's built in [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/).  This will allow you to use standard Django based field attributes on the IntegerField as well.  For example, you could limit the range of allowable integers to the available regions (i.e. 1-8).

```
class Message(models.Model):
  # ...
  regions = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(min_value=1, max_value=8), default=list)
```

The `default=list` statement creates an empty list in the database in the event the parameter is not included.